# Using sanity with next js: Client error "Must be an attribute or a string key"

Tags: next.js, sanity

I'm working with next-sanity for creating the client, but I keep getting the " Client error: Must be an attribute or a string key" error.

This is my config:

```
import { createClient, createImageUrlBuilder } from "next-sanity"

const config = {

  dataset: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SANITY_DATASET || "production",
  projectId: "ekdlavlv",
  useCdn: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production",

}

export const urlFor = (source) => createImageUrlBuilder(config).image(source)

// Set up the client for fetching data in the getProps page functions
export const sanityClient = createClient(config)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using `next-sanity@0.5.0` or later, you won't import `createImageUrlBuilder` from `next-sanity` but from `@sanity/image-url`. See here for the [migration details](https://github.com/sanity-io/next-sanity#createimageurlbuilder-is-removed).